# Django: How do I update only ONE record in my database?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to update a single (record) object in my database.

```
context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.update(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

I use objects.update, but it updates ALL my objects fk. How do I achieve only updating one object? I have also tried this:

```
context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.update_or_create(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

But this creates a new object and does not update the record that I want to update. I know why it creates a new objects, and it is because the FK I'm trying to update is null. Surely, there must be a way to only update and not create a single record? What am I missing here?

I tried adding a filter, but it feels redundant? I tried this:

```
context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.filter(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).update(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

I did consider trying to create an ID of the FK instantly and not later on, but I couldn't really get that to work, but if I created an ID then the update_or_create would work because an ID would exist already, BUT I cannot believe that I can't update a **single object** without create?

If creating the ID earlier on is the only work around, I will have to figure out how.

Comment: The filtering will do nothing, since you update the items with the value that already have that value. Usually the filtering condition is *different* from the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1='some value')`

The filter gets your object (returns the `Queryset` with only that object), then the update changes some other field that is not the `PK` to whatever you want.

In your case probably something like this:

```
context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.filter(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).update(some_attribute='some value')
```

Comment: Hmm, it's a foreign key in the table, so I'm unsure what the filter should look like. The fk is called: **eval_relationer** so I would think to do something like this?

`context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.filter(eval_relationer=self.kwargs.get('id')).update(eval_relationer=self.kwargs.get('id'))`

However, this does nothing. Tried with get('pk') instead but also nothing.

Comment: The  `filter(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))` makes good sense, I just can't seem to figure out how to update the FK with the ID that has been generated.

Comment: If you're filtering on an `FK`, you need to have that other object already created - otherwise you will get `None` back, because the filter can't find it (because it doesn't exist). How/when that FK is being created is another issue entirely - but to get a single object, you run `.filter` to get it, then use `.update` to make whatever changes you need to do.

Comment: Yep I understand that, and the FK object is being created, without filter using update only I can get the fk I’d, but it changes all the objects fk to be that same fk because it’s updating all of them and not using filter. But I can’t get it to work with the filter -> update... can’t figure out the correct query in the update part.

Comment: Because the `.update` is not a query and doesn't query things. The `.update` is to update a particular attribute on the object that you retrieve with the filter. You could do this in two steps (maybe that will make more sense to you)... `temp = Model.objects.filter(eval_id=some_value)` (this returns 1 object ideally if it's an FK), then you would do something like `temp.update(attribute_i_want_to_change='some value')` ... the update command doesn't do any querying at all - only updating.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Hanny, I seem to understand the mechanics of it now. 

However, I still can't get it to work. It either updates **all** the values, or it does not update anything at all. Am I doing something wrong with the self.kwargs.get('pk') maybe? It's the PK I want to filter, then I want to update the PK. 

`context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.filter(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).update(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`

I can't see how else to write the code, it makes sense to me. I tried with id too, nothing happens either.

Comment: I've done it! Thanks so much for your help. I just had to tweak and really think about what I was trying to "filter". I ended up with this result 
`context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).update(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`

Comment: Glad to hear it's all sorted. As always on Stack Overflow - if my answer helped you please mark this as answered so others can find it more easily ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After help from @Hanny I've figured out was going wrong.

I was trying to filter by the eval_relationer_id, when I should have been filtering by the evaluation pk and getting that specific PK. Otherwise I would be updating ALL the values which is not what I wanted.

So by filtering by pk:

```
filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

And updating by the attribute / fk that I want to update

```
update(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

This is the end-result:

```
context['eval_list'] = Evaluering.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).update(eval_relationer_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Comment: Just a little side note: if someone has provided you an answer that works - it's typically best practice to mark their answer as the correct answer. For example: my answer was correct based on information given and should have been marked as such. Creating your own answer and marking it as the accepted answer is just extra steps that may not be as helpful to others in your situation, as the conversation in the comments below the original answer provide additional insight your answer does not.

Comment: Oh okay..sorry I was not aware. I just wanted to make a clear explanation of what I did with ur help.